Vuetify 3 v-select not printing all options
EDIT: Here is an example: Vuetify Playground
I recently made a migration from Vue 2 to Vue 3 and fixing errors with the included Vuetify upgrade. I have a v-select which should show all the countries in additionalCitizenshipQuestion.countries, which is like 200 countries or so.
In Vue 2 when I pressed the select it only printed like 30-40 and when I scrolled it sort of auto expanded the scrollbar until I reached the 200th country (if that makes sense).
However, now in Vue 3 it only prints out the first 67 countries of the list and I have no idea why. Here is the v-select component with its additional items:
    <v-select density="compact" variant="outlined" :label="$t(additionalCitizenshipQuestion.label)"
        :items="additionalCitizenshipQuestion.countries" v-model="additionalCitizenship" item-value="code" item-title="name"
        multiple="mulitple">
        <template v-slot:item="{ item, attrs, on }">
          <v-list-item v-on="on" v-bind="attrs">
            <div class="country-dropdown-list">
              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-checkbox v-model="additionalCitizenship" :value="item.value" style="height: 40px;"></v-checkbox>
              </v-list-item-action>
              <v-list-item-content class="country-list-item-content">
                <v-list-item-icon>
                  <country-flag :country="item.value" />
                </v-list-item-icon>
                <v-list-item-title>
                  {{ item.props.title }}
                </v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </div>
          </v-list-item>
        </template>
      </v-select>
    <template>

And the countries list is built like this:
    [
        {
            "code": "AD",
            "name": "Andorra"
        },
        {
            "code": "AE",
            "name": "United Arab Emirates"
        },
        {
            "code": "AF",
            "name": "Afghanistan"
        },
        {
            "code": "AG",
            "name": "Antigua and Barbuda"
        },
        ...
    ]

Why is it now showing all my countries in the list?

Can you do a reproducible example? v-list-item-content and v-list-item-icon is vuetify2. Probably has something to do with not passing props correctly in the slot

@fOURP I added an example at the top of the question

Try changing "attrs" to "props"

@fOURP, thanks! Although it prints the name of the country twice in the dropdown

Wrap what's inside  the v-list-item in a <template #title> and it should be ok. Or you can prolly just remove the v-list-item-title. Whatever suits you

I think there is an issue within your slot usage. By removing it all items are displayed

You can use v-autocomplete for large lists
v-autocomplete handle large lists better:
<v-autocomplete
  density="compact"
  variant="outlined"
  :label="$t(additionalCitizenshipQuestion.label)"
  :items="additionalCitizenshipQuestion.countries"
  v-model="additionalCitizenship"
  item-value="code"
  item-title="name"
  multiple
>
  <template v-slot:item="{ item, attrs, on }">
    <v-list-item v-on="on" v-bind="attrs">
      <div class="country-dropdown-list">
        <v-list-item-action>
          <v-checkbox v-model="additionalCitizenship" :value="item.code" style="height: 40px;"></v-checkbox>
        </v-list-item-action>
        <v-list-item-content class="country-list-item-content">
          <v-list-item-icon>
            <country-flag :country="item.code" />
          </v-list-item-icon>
          <v-list-item-title>
            {{ item.name }}
          </v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </div>
    </v-list-item>
  </template>
</v-autocomplete>

You can also check Virtual Scrolling, can use a virtual scrolling component to handle large lists more efficiency.
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/virtual-scroller/#usage
And if both not working try manipulation with css (not the recommended solution):
<style>
.v-select__content {
  max-height: 300px; /* Adjust height as needed */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.no-wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.v-select__content .v-list-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>


None of these works for me, the last is not really an option either since it should be dynamic. Please see small example in the edit at the top of the question.

As i said early, v-virtual-scroll works:
<template>
  <v-select
    density="compact"
    variant="outlined"
    :label="returnObject.additionalCitizenshipQuestion.label"
    :items="returnObject.additionalCitizenshipQuestion.countries"
    v-model="additionalCitizenship"
    item-value="code"
    item-title="name"
    multiple
    :menu-props="{ closeOnContentClick: false }"
  >
    <v-virtual-scroll>
      <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
        <v-list-item>
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-checkbox></v-checkbox>
          </v-list-item-action>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="item.props.title"></v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </template>
    </v-virtual-scroll>
  </v-select>
</template>

v-select works fine without it but when you add v-list-item you need v-virtual-scroll supports to handle dynamic height and scrolling vertically
